# case statement with $servername fails

Tags: mysql, puppet, files

I'm exploring puppet on a standalone system and ran into a wall with copying a config file for MySQL.  Using the manifest below, MySQL is installed but the my.cnf file is not copied over.

init.pp (hostname: dev_one.site.com)

```
class mysql {

  case $servername {
    "prod_one.site.com", "dev_one.site.com", "sandbox_one.site.com": {
      $conf_file    = 'my.cnf.one'
    }
    "prod_two.site.com", "dev_two.site.com", "sandbox_two.site.com": {
      $conf_file    = 'my.cnf.two'
    }
  }


  package { "mysql-server":
    ensure => present,
  }

  package { "mysql":
    ensure => present,
  }

  file { 'my.cnf':
    path    => '/etc/',
    ensure  => file,
    require => Package['mysql'],
    source  => "puppet:///modules/mysql/${conf_file}"
  }

  service { "mysqld":
    ensure => running,
    enable => true,
    require => Package["mysql-server"]
  }

}
```

And here is the result:

```
[root@dev_one manifests]# puppet apply --verbose ./init.pp 
Info: Applying configuration version '1379018555'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql/Package[mysql-server]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql/Service[mysqld]/ensure: ensure changed 'stopped' to 'running'
Info: /Stage[main]/Mysql/Service[mysqld]: Unscheduling refresh on Service[mysqld]
Notice: Finished catalog run in 14.34 seconds

[root@dev_one manifests]# ll /etc/my*
total 0
```

No errors, but my.cnf is not being copied.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is servername being defined?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using hostname?  That is actually set in facter unlike servername.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, where is `$servername` being set?  That's not a standard fact, so for it to have content you'd need to have either a custom fact or manifest variable.  Do you want to be using `$clientcert` or `$fqdn` instead?

On your `file` resource.. I would think that should be erroring out, but maybe not, since `/etc/` exists.. the problem there is that the resource as declared is trying to manage `/etc/` instead of `/etc/my.cnf`.  Either declare the full path to the file in the resource name and omit the `path` parameter:

```
file { '/etc/my.cnf':
```

Or, have the `path` parameter be the full path to the file (then the name is irrelevant):

```
file { 'MySQL Config':
    path    => '/etc/my.cnf',
```

---

But.. I'd really recommend against having the logic of "which config file does this server get" hardcoded in your manifest.  Use Hiera or node definitions with parameterized classes instead.

Comment: Updated my manifest with your second example - works fine now.